# Simple parallax effect, not giving the right effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make it so that when I scroll down, it pushes the header text down a bit, i.e adds margin on top, so it remains in the view.

This is the exact effect I am trying to get, with the header text:
http://www.leeannpica.com/

I've spent hours on this but I can only get this close:
http://hiven.com/parallax.html

It uses this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(".logo").css('margin', '-' + (100 - fromTop) + 'px 0px 0px 0px');
});
```

I can't seem to get anywhere close to the same effect as you can see. Can anyone please help me understand how to tweak the javascript to get an effect similar to the first link?

Comment: Why don't you do it in CSS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you asked to use JavaScript,

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
$(".logo").css({"margin":fromTop/3+"px 0px 0px 0px"});
});
```

In parallax effect you want thing to move at different rates with respect to each other.So the rate with which the header was moving is reduced by a factor of 3 i.e "fromTop/3".You can play with this to get the desired results.

you can view a demo [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EorbZJ)

or you can take help from [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/parallax.html).(it is easy to use)